# How can I create cron jobs in specific files?

Tags: linux, centos, cron

I want to have a separate folders for `cron` jobs like:

`/mydata/cronjobs`

Now in that folder I want to have files like `backup_server` which will have the content like:

```
30 3 * * 1-5 /home/user/scripts/backup.sh 
30 3 * * 1-5 /home/user/scripts/backup2.sh
```

Similarly, I want to have more files in that directory for each separate `cron` job so that I can centralize and separate the `cron` jobs from one folder.

How can I make root run those jobs for all files in that folder?

Comment: Doesn't CentOS already provide `/etc/cron.d` for this sort of arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

How about a script like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

cronjobs_dir=/mydata/cronjobs
crontab_tmp=/tmp/crontab

crontab -l > "$crontab_tmp"
for i in $mydir/*
do
    cat "$i" >> "$crontab_tmp"
done
crontab "$crontab_tmp"
```

Comment: I think you mean `for i in $mydir/*`. Parsing `ls` output is useless and the `ls` itself is also [useless](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls).

Comment: Or more succinctly `( crontab -l; cat "$mydir"/* ) | crontab -`

Comment: But then there is no facility for, say, removing one job but keeping the others (programmatically).

Comment: @tripleee You are right, with a little more thinking before posting, I could have optimized out `ls`, but I didn't know that you can actually use STDIN with `crontab`. I should have read the manpage. Thank you for pointing this out!
"Removing and keeping the others": 
It's like removing everything and re-adding what's needed. And I assumed that: a, only those files/jobs are in the directory which are actually needed. b, all the files/jobs are there which are needed.